# Microsoft Outlook 365 Click-to-Run: How to search Contacts for parts of an address

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I just uninstalled Office 2007, purchased a Microsoft 365 Subscription and installed the Microsoft 365 suite of applications on my Windows 10 machine.

In Outlook I click on the Contacts icon and contacts are displayed.  In the Outlook search bar, I enter part of the name of a contact.  Matching contacts appear.  So far, so good.  Now I type a zipcode.  Nothing appears.  I know absolutely that I have contacts with the provided zipcode, but Outlook won't find them.  Same with city name.  Same with anything except the name of the contact.

In Outlook 2007 you just type something in the search field and it will find it.

The only work-around I came up with is `View > Arrange By > View Settings... > Filter` and then provide part of the address and in the `In:` field you must select "address fields only."  This is really clunky and non-intuitive.

How can I easily search for a contact by zipcode or city name?

Comment: Is your Windows Index up to date?  I just searched for Postal Code in the Search Bar at the top of Outlook and it found the four contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a repair of the entire office suite and that fixed the problem.  It did not occur to me to do a repair earlier because I only JUST installed this software 3 days ago.

Comment: Glad to see that you have resolved your issue.

Comment: By the way, would you mind marking your own reply as answer so that others who might have a similar question can benefit from your thread?